# How do I edit an Access ADP file?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003, adp

So I have this Access Database Project file that I have been tasked to edit.  I have Access 2003 and 2007 installed.  The ADP only supports 2003 for some reason.  Anyway, the issue I have is that I can't figure out how to get to the VBA code in behind things.

The previous developers have done a very good job of locking everything down on the GUI such that the only thing I get when I open the application is a notice saying that it can't find the database on the server.  (More than likely there is a problem there too, but since I can't look at code I don't know for sure.)

Does anyone know how to get around the GUI lockdown that has gone on here?

Michael

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it turns out, you can edit an ADP file that has all of the form information turned off by finding the file using Windows Explorer by highlighting the file, then hold shift, and then hit enter.  You continue to hold shift until the interface is loaded.